# Integral Of $\frac{x^4+2x+4}{x^4-1}$

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

Any ideas how to solve it? 
$$\int\frac{x^4+2x+4}{x^4-1}dx$$
Thanks!

Comment: By the way, the trick to notice that your integrand is $1+\frac {2x+5}{x^4-1}$ is to "add zero": $$\frac{x^4+2x+4}{x^4-1} = \frac{x^4 -1 + 1+2x+4}{x^4-1} = \frac{x^4 -1}{x^4 - 1} + \frac{1+2x+4}{x^4-1}. $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using polynomial division, we get $$\int \frac{x^4+2x+4}{x^4-1} dx = \int 1 + \frac{2x+5}{(x^2 - 1)(x^2 + 1)}dx
 = \int 1 + \frac{2x+5}{(x+1)(x-1)(x^2+1)} dx  $$

Expressing this as partial fractions, we need only find $A, B, C$

$$=  \int \left(1 + \frac{A}{x+1} + \frac B{x-1} +\frac{C}{x^2 + 1}\right)\,dx$$

And then the integration is pretty straightforward.

Comment: I think is CX+D in the last fraction right?

Comment: Ahhh...yes...fixed...! ;-)

Comment: $2x+5 = x^3(A+B+D)+x^2(B-A+C)+x(A+B-D)+1(B-A-C)$ this is the final equation , now need to find the parameters,thanks!

Comment: Actually, you don't need $CX + D$ in the numerator here: it turns out that $C$ is sufficient. I used $$2x + 5 = A(x - 1)(x^2 +1) + B(x+1)(x^2 + 1) + C(x-1)(x+1)$$ and solved for $A$ when $x = -1$, for $B$ when $x = 1$, and for $C$ when $x = 0,$ given $A, B$

Comment: Nice to get the feedback! +1

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**
$$
\frac{x^4+2x+4}{x^4-1} = 1 + \frac{2x+5}{x^4-1}
 = 1 + \frac{2x+5}{(x+1)(x-1)(x^2+1)}
$$
and use partial fractions.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  First, make the integrand into $1+\frac {2x+5}{x^4-1}$  Now apply partial fractions.