# Integral of $\int \frac{x^4+2x+4}{x^4-1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

I am trying to solve this integral and I need your suggestions.
$$\int \frac{x^4+2x+4}{x^4-1}dx$$
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? You could use partial fraction decomposition to reduce the integral to table integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

welcome to math.stackexchange this question were answered already.
[Here is the link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384553/integral-of-fracx42x4x4-1)
use polynomial division, we get $$\int \frac{x^4+2x+4}{x^4-1} dx = \int 1 + \frac{2x+5}{(x^2 - 1)(x^2 + 1)}dx
 = \int 1 + \frac{2x+5}{(x+1)(x-1)(x^2+1)} dx  $$

Expressing this as partial fractions, we need only find $A, B, C$

$$=  \int \left(1 + \frac{A}{x+1} + \frac B{x-1} +\frac{CX+D}{x^2 + 1}\right)\,dx$$

Comment: If you know where it has been answered, it is good to post the link in the comments to the question.  If you put some text in square brackets and follow with the link in parentheses, the text will print and be a link.

Answer (score 3):

Note that this problems *cries out* for [partial fraction decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction#Examples), for which you'll want to factor you denominator: it factors nicely as the difference of squares:

$$(x^4 - 1) = (x^2 + 1)(x^2 - 1) = (x^2 + 1)(x +1)(x-1)$$

See also Paul's Online Notes: [Partial Fractions](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/PartialFractions.aspx) for more insight into using this technique for integration, and some nicely worked out examples.

Comment: Nice guidance +1

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Using [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html)  formula,

$$\frac{x^4+2x+4}{x^4-1}=1+\frac{ax+b}{x^2+1}+\frac c{x+1}+\frac d{x-1}$$ where $a,b,c,d$ are arbitrary constants to determined by equating the coefficients of the different powers of $x$ in

$$x^4+2x+4=x^4-1+(x^2-1)(ax+b)+c(x-1)(x^2+1)+d(x+1)(x^2+1)$$

Comment: Great formula you shared here!

Comment: @NasuSama, please have a look into the link

Comment: @lab_bhattarchjee, Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Math Stack Exchange!

With lab bhattacharjee's helpful hint for the integral, we can rewrite the expression as:

$$\int \left(1 + \frac{(-2x - 5)}{2(x^2 + 1)} + \frac{7}{4(x - 1)} - \frac{3}{4(x + 1)}\right)dx$$

$$= \int 1 dx + \int \frac{(-2x - 5)}{2(x^2 + 1)} dx + \int \frac{7}{4(x - 1)} dx - \int \frac{3}{4(x + 1)} dx$$

$$= \int 1 dx - \int \frac{2x}{2(x^2 + 1)} dx - \int \frac{5}{2(x^2 + 1)} + \int \frac{7}{4(x - 1)} dx - \int \frac{3}{4(x + 1)} dx$$

$$= \int 1 dx - \int \frac{x}{x^2 + 1} dx - \frac{5}{2} \int \frac{1}{x^2 + 1} dx + \frac{7}{4} \int \frac{1}{x - 1} dx - \frac{3}{4} \int \frac{1}{x + 1} dx$$

Next steps should be "direct-cut", meaning that it's really possible to work out the computation one way! :D

- For the *first* integrand, use power rule to obtain $x$.
- For the *second* integrand, let $u = x^2 + 1 \rightarrow du = 2x dx$.
- For the *third* integrand, you get $\arctan(x)$.  You can find the special integral [here](http://math2.org/math/integrals/tableof.htm).
- For the *fourth* integrand, let $v = x - 1 \rightarrow dv = dx$.
- For the *fifth* integrand, let $w = x + 1 \rightarrow dw = dx$.

So we are left off with:

$$x - \frac{5}{2}arctan(x) - \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{du}{u} + \frac{7}{4} \int \frac{dv}{v} - \frac{3}{4}  \int \frac{dw}{w}$$

Finally, the expression becomes...

$$x - \frac{5}{2}arctan(x) - \frac{ln(u)}{2} + \frac{7ln(v)}{4} - \frac{3ln(w)}{4} + K \text{ where } K \text{ is an arbitrary constant}$$
$$= x - \frac{5}{2}arctan(x) - \frac{ln(x^2 + 1)}{2} + \frac{7ln(x - 1)}{4} - \frac{3ln(x + 1)}{4} + K$$

The solution for the integral is equivalent to the one in [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28x%5E4+%2B+2x+%2B+4%29%2F%28x%5E4+-+1%29).